# webserver for a Backbone app?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, webkit, makefile

Sorry this might be a total noob question

I downloaded a backbone example app from github https://github.com/elfsternberg/The-Backbone-Store that, according to its README, "must be installed under a webserver in order to operate correctly." Indeed, when I open the index file in Chrome, it just displays an html/css with no javascript functionality, with this error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/me/Sites/backbonestore/data/items.json. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I think this might be because of these links in the json data file

```
"url": "http://www.amazon.com/Door-Religious-Knives/dp/B001FGW0UQ/?tag=quirkey-20"
```

The tutorial says I need a webserver, even though it doesn't use a database.

Is there a way to use webkit (I normally work in the Rails environment) when I'm not using Rails?  If that's not the problem, then can you explain how I might get it to work?

One difference between this backbone project and others I have looked at is that it has a make file.  Do I have to do anything with that?

The make file

```
.SUFFIXES: .nw .js .pdf .html .tex 

NOTANGLE=       notangle
NOWEAVE=        noweave
ECHO=           /bin/echo

all: index.html store.js 

.nw.html:
    $(NOWEAVE) -filter l2h -delay -x -index -autodefs c -html $*.nw > $*.html

.nw.tex:
    $(NOWEAVE) -x -delay $*.nw > $*.tex             #$

.tex.pdf:
    xelatex $*.tex; \
    while grep -s 'Rerun to get cross-references right' $*.log; \
        do \
        xelatex *$.tex; \
    done

.nw.js:
    @ $(ECHO) $(NOTANGLE) -c -R$@ $<
    @ - $(NOTANGLE) -c -R$@ $< > $*.nw-js-tmp
    @ if [ -s "$*.nw-js-tmp" ]; then \
        mv $*.nw-js-tmp $@; \
    else \
        echo "$@ not found in $<"; \
    rm $*.nw-js-tmp; \
    fi  

store.js: backbonestore.nw
    @ $(ECHO) $(NOTANGLE) -c -R$@ $<
    @ - $(NOTANGLE) -c -R$@ $< > $*.nw-html-tmp
    @ if [ -s "$*.nw-html-tmp" ]; then \
        mv $*.nw-html-tmp $@; \
    else \
        echo "$@ not found in $<"; \
    rm $*.nw-tmp; \
    fi  

index.html: backbonestore.nw
    @ $(ECHO) $(NOTANGLE) -c -R$@ $<
    @ - $(NOTANGLE) -c -R$@ $< > $*.nw-html-tmp
    @ if [ -s "$*.nw-html-tmp" ]; then \
        mv $*.nw-html-tmp $@; \
    else \
        echo "$@ not found in $<"; \
    rm $*.nw-tmp; \
    fi  


clean:
    - rm -f *.tex *.dvi *.aux *.toc *.log *.out *.html *.js

realclean: clean
    - rm -f *.pdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue here is may be you are trying to access the application in chrome and there is a known issue in chrome which cannot open file paths if you see the file path starts with `file:///` instead of `file://` You can use any web server for that matter of fact just that you can access these path by a localhost url. try opening this same file in Firefox it should just work fine

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing a small static file web server like [node-static](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static). Just `npm install -g node-static` (requires [node.js](http://nodejs.org)), then -- in your `The-Backbone-Store/`directory -- type `static`. You should now be able to use by visiting `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: thanks, it works in firefox as @kishore suggested. However, I'm going to install node-static anyways, so thanks for answering.  btw, can you say why it would need a webserver?